# JavaFX problema - rootLayout cannot be resolved

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Necesito ayuda con esto, rootLayout.setCenter (SecondView); no funciona, estoy trabajando con JavaFX y SceneBuilder. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

```
       public void showPersonOverview() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("SecondView.fxml"));
            AnchorPane SecondView = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            //The error is behind. Its says: rootLayout cannot be resolved
            rootLayout.setCenter(SecondView);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            SecondViewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que declarar e iniciar la variable rootLayout, ejemplo:

declaración:

```
 private BorderPane rootLayout;
```

inicialización:

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
```

Como guía te puede servir este ejemplo en el cual se llama el método `initRootLayout()` , el cual dentro realiza la inicialización de la variable `rootLayout`:

https://github.com/marcojakob/tutorial-javafx-8/blob/master/AddressApp-Part-6/src/ch/makery/address/MainApp.java

Answer (score 0):

No se como estás usando los paneles, pero en este caso podría ser así:

- Usa un border pane donde deseas mostrar a "SecondView.fxml"
- En el center del border pane podrías mostrar a "SecondView.fxml" de la siguiente forma:

  ```
  void mostrarPanel {

  FXMLLoader loader;
  Parent p;
  loader = new FXMLLoader();
  loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("SecondView.fxml"));
  try {
      loader.load();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.err.println("Error al cargar SecondView.fxml");
      Logger.getLogger(miClase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } //del try catch
  p = (Parent) loader.getRoot();
  BorderPane.setCenter(p);
  ```

  }